# Swift Class Extension - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

When creating a class extension on a foundation class I get a `unrecognized selector sent to instance` when using the following:

```
extension NSURLSessionDataTask: Taskable {

  func isRunning() -> Bool {
    return state == .Running
  }

}
```

Error:

```
[__NSCFLocalDataTask isRunning]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa93bdc07d0
```

I am trying to create a common task interface so I am able to use different kinds of classes such as operations and session tasks, is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of Cocoa classes are "class clusters", meaning you may get a different one from what you asked for. `NSCFLocalDataTask` is a private class and looks like it doesn't inherit from `NSURLSessionDataTask`. Try moving your extension to `NSURLSessionTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Why this might happen: Objective-C BOOL properties starting with "is" may be handled differently. It may be that your func is exported to Objective-C as the "running" method, not as "isRunning".

Comment: I have tried several method names, `[__NSCFLocalDataTask areWeRunning]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` to ensure i was not introducing a collision somewhere