# XCSourceEditorCommandInvocation swift extension causes "unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, xcode-extension

When I try and add swift extensions to classes in `XcodeKit` (framework for adding Xcode extensions) the compiler is happy to build without any errors, but when the code runs I get the following exception:

```
-[XCSourceEditorCommandInvocation test]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc60543f2b0
```

Below is sample code which can reproduce the exception:

```
class SourceEditorCommand: NSObject, XCSourceEditorCommand {
    func perform(with invocation: XCSourceEditorCommandInvocation, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void ) -> Void {
        // Call extension method
        invocation.test() // <--- Exception thrown here

        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}

extension XCSourceEditorCommandInvocation {
    func test() {
        print("it works!")
    }
}
```

I've extended ObjC classes in swift in the past without any issues so I'm a bit stuck here.

I've tried:

- adding `@objc` before the method declaration.
- adding `public` to the extension and method.
- I'm not extending a class cluster so it's likely not [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847999/swift-class-extension-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance).
- I'm not extending a protocol so it's likely not [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809253/swift-using-protocol-extension-results-in-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither Objective-C categories nor Swift extensions are supported on the classes or types in XcodeKit.framework at this time.